# visual studio 2010: error code -2146232576 (0x80131700)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to convert a C++ project from visual studio 2008 running on Windows XP to 2010 running on Seven. Compilation seems to run perfectly but during the debugging I have an error: "The program 'App.exe : Native' has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700)."
After a few researches on the internet I found out that the issue is in relation with .NET.
I tried to update my windows with hidden updates, check what the .NET version target is 4 and a few more things that doesn't work...

Has anyone ever encountered this issue ? 
Thanks a lot.
EDIT: it is a **managed** C++ project

Comment: If it is a C++ project then .NET should not be an issue. Have you tried debugging your project, stepping trough the code and seeing at which line the error occurs?

Comment: Installing the latest version of the .NET framework worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

It is a low-level .NET initialization error, the CLR cannot get loaded.  That's pretty hard to explain since you can run VS2010 without a problem and it already uses .NET version 4.  The only decent guess is that you are actually using a C++ project (not a C++/CLI one) and that it loads the CLR itself.  And asks for and old version, like 1.1, one that isn't installed on the machine.  Search the code for "CorBindToRuntime".

Comment: Well actually i'm using managed c++, so c++/cli...sorry to not have mentioned that before.
I cannot find "CorBindToRuntime" in the code.

Comment: Something is broken on your machine and I don't know what.  Try it on another machine first before you do anything drastic.

Comment: The solution does work on XP and visual studio 2008. I'll try to find one another machine...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all Windows updates lately? If not, do so - seems to be some general .NET related error - see:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/wlgeneraldev/thread/8f9d610f-92b2-4262-8e1a-88cee8428aed

Comment: I've seen that link before and yes I updated everything I found about .NET updates.

Answer (score 0):

You are running native code I presume? Are you? 
If that is a case this error is caused by something else.

If you are using managed C++ than you have a problem related to the .Net framework.

Remember that some error numbers returned may (and they do) indicate different causes, depending who return an error.

Giving more information about what is your application doing and what language it is written would definitely help isolation problem.